# iOS Simulator not updating location

Tags: ios, swift2

The below code worked just one time and now all of the sudden it is not showing a point of interest (POI). I tried it on two different machines and am getting the same behavior. This is what has me puzzled, is it the code or my simulator settings.

I cleaned the project, made sure I had the simulator on custom. I did have the longitude and latitude printing now all of a sudden it is not printing in the console either.

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

var manager:CLLocationManager!
var latitude:Double = 0.0
var longitude:Double = 0.0
var location:Double = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("init")
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy - kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print("test test test")

    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
    self.latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    self.longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Army Recruiting"

    request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 1600, 1600)

    MKLocalSearch(request: request).startWithCompletionHandler { (response, error) in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        guard let response = response else { return }
        guard response.mapItems.count > 0 else { return }

        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(response.mapItems.count)))
        let mapItem = response.mapItems[randomIndex]

        mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(nil)
    }

    print("\(self.longitude) \(self.latitude)")

}
```

----------------------UPDATE 1--------------------

Updating location via simulator

[image]

I have noticed the below function is not running:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations 
locations: [CLLocation])
```

---------------------Update 2--------------------

The app worked once then stopped. Not sure what is going on. Yes I added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of issues with your code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("init")
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy - kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

Replace with:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("init")
    manager = CLLocationManager()
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

**ADDITIONALLY (for info)**

You can create GPX files for different locations.

You can also simulate routes with in the GPX files - have a delve into the Apple Documentation which shows you hows to set the GPX files to your target build. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/CustomizingYourExperienceThroughXcodeSchemes/CustomizingYourExperienceThroughXcodeSchemes.html

There is also a good tutorial here with links for creating GPX files and routes which i have used in the past and is very useful. https://blackpixel.com/writing/2013/05/simulating-locations-with-xcode.html

Comment: the locationManager func is not executing. I confirmed by putting print() statements inside the function. I am not to sure why it is not running.

Comment: Does the app as for location services to be used?

Comment: Only asking cause it sounds like you have not set up NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription (in your case) in your .plist file.

Goto your target > info and add a line with NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and the String would be the reason why you want the use to accept Location Services for the app

Comment: please see update-2. Yes I have that in there. The app worked once then just stopped. I restarted my computer then thought I would try a different machine. So I put it on GIT, pulled it, and the same thing happened on the other machine.

Comment: Also you will need a to add `manager.startUpdatingLocation()` after `manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`

Comment: Sorry the Update 2 did not come through on a refresh for some reason

Comment: Trying to get there! 
`manager.desiredAccuracy - kCLLocationAccuracyBest` should be `manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest`

Comment: Cool :) Glad to be of assistance @Drew1208

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! You fixed two things for me. I had to add manager.startUpdatingLocation() then go to the simulator and choose a custom location. Also yes I needed to fix this tooL manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94738/discussion-between-zappidev-and-drew1208).

Comment: For future reference if you are build for < iOS8 you will need to wrap and ensure you capture previous version ways of Location Services otherwise it will fail.
Swift has a nice wrapper `if #available(iOS 8.0, *) { ... } else { //iOS7 ... }`

Comment: True but I used guard.

Comment: After this - didUpdateLocation is getting called but didEnterRegion/Exit is not called.
I am using XCode 11.0 and simulator is on iOS 13.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The simulator can have a set of hard coded locations, and you change them or disable them in the console of xcode.

It should look like this:

[image]

If you want to test real moving location you should test it on a device.